# Cache contains different data for subdomains

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to ask about strange behavior of Cache object. I use Cache to store data specific for user (more accurately for session) with SessionID as a key.

For some reason the data in Cache appears not to be the same for different subdomains. I managed to keep SessionID equal across all subdomains:
 - I set domain attribute in httpCookies element in web config like ".domain.com".
 - I used [this](http://www.know24.net/blog/ASPNET+Session+State+Cookies+And+Subdomains.aspx) trick to ensure that SessionID cookie is stored across all subdomains.
 - I set sessionState mode to SQLServer.

I ensured that SessionID is really the same for all subdomains. What's more, it is interesting that when I use session state in place of cache, everything works just fine. Session returns expected data for all subdomains. But when I use cache with SessionID as a key, cache returns different data for different subdomain.

Of course, I could keep it in session state but I'm not really fan of it and try to avoid it whenever I can.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're underlying cache is an HttpRuntimeCache, there's one per process (i.e. per App Pool).  Is this one host-header site running on a single server in a single app pool?  If not, you have multiple instances of HttpRuntimeCache.

Comment: All the subdomains point to the same IP. I suppose it's the same app pool then.

Answer (score 0):

> What's more, it is interesting that when I use session state in place
>   of cache, everything works just fine.

It works because you store SessionState in centralized location which is SQLServer.

[The Cache for the current application domain.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

If you want to have same cache for all app domains, you need distributed caching such as *Windows Server AppFabric*

Comment: I forgot to state that all the subdomains are the same application. I mean all the subdomains point to one IP. Shouldn't the application domain be the same as well?